# Include Path to flask_http_request_exceptions_total

Tags: python, flask, prometheus, grafana

I'm looking for a way to include the path as a label for **flask_http_request_exceptions_total** metric? I'm using the prometheus-flask-exporter for this.

I registered path label as default but it is not included for the Exception case. Whereas it works perfectly fine for the **flask_http_request_duration_seconds_sum**.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
    metrics = PrometheusMetrics(app)
    # register additional default metrics
    metrics.register_default(
        metrics.counter(
            'by_path_counter', 'Request count by request paths',
            labels={'path': lambda: request.path}
        )
    )
```

[image: images]